# How to map buttons in html to running an executable file

Tags: html, linux, apache

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Led On/Off</h1>

<input type="button" value="Led on" onclick="RunFile();"/>
<input type="button" value="Led off" onclick="RunFile();"/>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my html code. I'd link to map those buttons to 2 executable files to switch on and off led in wandboard. How will i do it?

Comment: usually a webpage is not the best place to implement this. Is the LED connected to the computer that hosts the webpage or the client?

Comment: Led is connected to the gpio port of the computer(in this case wandboard-server). I'd like to turn it on and off from a different pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment the LED is connected to the **Server** while you try toggle it from a **client**.

Since the HTML Page you send to the client is then rendered locally (on the CLIENT) you will have to create some kind of **LED Toggle Service** on the **Server**.
You would add a call to the Service to your HTML page. This for example could be a link:

```
<a href="myLEDService/LED/ON"> Led On </a>
<a href="myLEDService/LED/OFF"> Led Off </a>
```

I can only speculate what your *executeable* to toggle the LED is, and based on the assumption that the `apache` tag you added is accurate you might want to have a look at [Apache CGI](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html)

Answer (score 0):

If this webpage is running directly as a file (as opposed to being accessed on a webserver via http://), you should be able to open other files that are accessible to the client browser

`<button onclick="window.open('file:///C:/folder/file.exe')">
    Launch notepad
</button>`

Comment: is this same for linux also??